# URL masking to subdomain redirecting to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, url-rewriting

I am trying to change the URL of a Joomla site in browser my original URL is like

```
example.com/marketsite/abc
```

and I want to change it to

```
abc.example.com/marketsite/abc
```

I am using following code in Htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^marketsite/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/marketsite
```

It is redirecting the site to subdomain and changing the URL but site is not not working now which was working on

```
example.com/marketsite/abc
```

Comment: "URL masking" - as you have found, you can't easily "mask" the URL when changing the domain, mod_rewrite will naturally trigger an external redirection - but I assume this is what you want to do anyway? Is the site configured to work on the subdomain?

Comment: Define "not working".